# Does Visual C# have all the features of TSQL in terms of data management and manipulation?

Tags: sql-server, c#

As it is possible to query SQL Server both with Visual C# and TSQL, I want to know are they all equal in terms of operators and features available, or TSQL has more features which cannot be implemented using Visual C#(kind of administrative operators which do not have equivalent in C#)?

Comment: The question is very broad, but if you're using System.Data.SqlClient, then you can provide the T-SQL to be executed in your application (as a SqlCommand), so in theory, everything you can do via T-SQL you can do in C#.

Comment: But what if we do not use tsql at all?

Comment: "*it is possible to query SQL Server with Visual C#*" - that is plain wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As it is possible to query SQL Server both with Visual C# and TSQL

No, it is *not* possible to query SQL Server with C# (the "Visual" part was dropped a long time ago and is not used anymore; it's difficult to even find references to "Visual C#" at this point). T-SQL is the *only* language that queries SQL Server.

There are wrappers that provide a higher-level interface to T-SQL, such as **SMO**, **LINQ to SQL**, and **Entity Framework**. Each of those options merely mask the T-SQL that is submitted to accomplish the operation represented in that particular form. This is similar, in a sense, to **SQL Server Management Studio** (SSMS), **Azure Data Studio**, **Server Explorer** in Visual Studio, or any other GUI allowing you to interact with SQL Server without you needing to remember and type the T-SQL yourself. But, at least in SSMS, there is a "Script" button at the top of all (or most) windows that will show you the T-SQL that will be submitted if you click the "OK" button in whatever window you are in. Even getting a list of databases, or objects (tables, views, stored procedures,etc) to populate Object Explorer / Server Explorer are done via `SELECT` statements.

You can use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see all of the T-SQL submitted by these GUIs and your app code. **LINQ to SQL** and **Entity Framework** use `sp_executesql` for queries with variables / parameters, and that *might* show up as an RPC call.

So no, none of those wrapper options implement 100% of the functionality of T-SQL. Nor do they allow you do determine *how* to structure the query if there are choices (e.g. `NOT IN` vs `NOT EXISTS()`, etc). These wrappers provide convenience (to .NET developers), not flexibility.